# Navbar Sizing on various screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to make a navbar that will run throughout my website. Unfortunately, on smaller screens the buttons on top pop below the black bar. I've tried and tried to fix this without luck. How do I make it such that all aspects of the navbar stay in line up top in large, medium and small screens?

```
<!--Navigation with Button -->
<?php
if(session_status()!==PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
    session_start();
include "header.php";

if(isset($_POST['search']))
    $search = $_POST['search'];
else
    $search = "";
?>

    <nav id="topbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">


                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="img/logo_front.png" alt=""></a>



                <form id="searchme" class="navbar-form pull-left" role="search" action="search.php" method="post">
                    <div class="input-group" display="inline" id="topinput">
                        <input id="topbarsearch" name="search" type="search" value="<?php echo $search;?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                        <span class="input-group-btn" id='search_btn'>
                            <button id="searchicon" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg" type="submit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" name="submit"></span>
                            </button>    
                    </div>  
                </form>

            <!--Button to Upload Information -->

            <div class="top_container">
                <div class="call-to-action">

                <div id="uploadbutton" class="nav navbar-right">    
                 <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid']!=''){
                 ?>
                      <a href="signout.php" id="logout" class="btn btn-m"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'] . " Sign Out";?></a>
                 <?php
                    }
                     ?>

                    <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="about.php" id="about_button_topbar">About Us</a> 

                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="create.php" id="signin_button_topbar">Sign In</a>

                    <a href="upload_choice.php" role="button" id="mybutton" class="btn btn-success">Upload</a>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- End Navigation with Button -->

///CSS

    #topbar{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    height:60px;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    }


    .navbar-default {
    border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;

    }

    #mybutton{
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-right:-60px;
    float:right;
    height:45px;

    }

    #signin_button_topbar{
    padding-top:10px;
    height:45px;
    margin-right:15px;

    }

    #about_button_topbar{
    padding-top:10px;
    height:45px;
    margin-right:15px;
    color:white;
   }
```

Comment: Your problem can be fixed with [responsive web design](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Media Queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en) as a [Responsive Web Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) technique to help deal with the issue. There are plenty of [tutorials out there](http://bfy.tw/3M4m), and you'll have to do some playing with it to get what you want, specifically. However, for a quick example:

The idea is that, within your CSS, you set a *media query* that help determine the screen size. Media queries are nothing more than a simple filter that basically says:

```
if (screen == big) 'use this css'
else if (screen == small) 'use this css'
```

I'll try below to insert an example, and you can simply test what I mean by either making your browser window different sizes, or opening developers tools and changing the layout to different mobile emulations. (*if you don't know how to do this, see [this article on how to do it with Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en)*)

> After a little testing, I found it's best to click the **Full Page** button that appears in *upper right* corner of *snippet* when you run it.

```css
#a, #b { color: #f8f8ff; padding: 1em; text-align: center; }

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  #a { background: blue; }
  #b { border-top: 1px solid; }
  }
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  #a { background: red; }
  }

#b { background: red; }
```

```html
<div id="a">
  This is a Blue Div when Big
  </div>
<div id="b">
  But it will turn as Red as this div when small
  </div>
```

[More information on Responsive Web Design](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)

*<sub>also you could google it</sub>*